# Covariance of 2 dimensional bivariate normal distribution

Tags: covariance, bivariate, noise

I'm forgetting my basics, so I must be being a silly sausage, but consider

$$X\sim N(0,1)$$
$$Y\sim N(0,1)$$
if $f(x,y)$ is the join probability of these 2 variables, then the 3D plot looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmvsk.gif).

I want to calculate the covariance of $(X,Y)$.

As $x$ and $y$ both get closer to the origin, $f(x,y)$ gets closer to 0. Surely there is some correlation between these variables - they both have higher values the closer they get to 0.

At the same time a normal distribution is typically used to model noise in a signal, so there shouldn't really be any covariance between two variables which follow.

I've managed to confuse myself.

Comment: Covariance can be found from $E(XY)$ which is worked out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315999/calculate-exy-for-x-y-sim-n-mu-1-mu-2-sigma-12-sigma-22?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the independent bivariate Gaussian is just one of (infinitely many) variables with standard normal marginal distributions. For example, assume quadrants I and III (counterclockwise) had zero probability. The marginals would still be normal, even while the joint clearly is not. In general, you cannot determine the exact joint distribution from the marginal distributions alone, but you can construct approximations given certain assumptions.

Secondly, correlation is a measure of linear variability about a joint mean. The fact that density is greatest at (0,0) does it describe what changes to expect from one variable when another changes value. Therefore, it does not reflect any correlation, just the coincidence of their respective means.